# How to solve segmentation fault in c?

Tags: c, cs50

When I was making my program I got an error type of thing called **Segmentation Fault**.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    char i = strlen(argv[2]);
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        printf("%i %s %hhd", argc, argv[2], i);
    }
}
```

I run this program using these commands

```
make substitution
```

and then

```
./substitution abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

In this we have to add a 26 word key which in the above line is a to z.

Please help if you know to solve

Comment: Please show how you are running the program. Seg fault likely caused because the program is not being run with enough command line args. `argc` should be checked **before** accessing any of the `argv` elements.

Comment: @RohanBari string comes from the library of cs50.h .

Comment: Okay @kaylum I will try.

Comment: @kaylum it is not working.

Comment: You still have not shown how you are running the program. And have you also made the changes in the answer below? You need to check that `argc == 3` rather than `2` if you want to access `argv[2]`.

Comment: Okay @kaylum , sorry I didn't understand I will try again that as I am a 10-year old kid(I am in grade 5)

Comment: @kaylum I have edited the question please see that.

Comment: Okay @kaylum thank for your help also but your code didn't made it but Rohan Bari's made. BTW thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invoke your program with:

```
./substitution abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

`argc` will be 2, and `argv` will be an array of 3 pointers:

`argv[0]` points to the string `./substitution`, `argv[1]` points to the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, and `argv[2]` is NULL.  If you attempt to compute the length of NULL by calling `strlen(argv[2])`, that is an error.  You must not pass NULL to `strlen`.  I think your error is simply mis-indexing the argv array.  Arrays in C are zero based.  If you want to compute the length of the first argument, you want to work with `argv[1]`, not `argv[2]`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
    if( argc > 1 ){
        size_t i = strlen(argv[1]);
        printf("%i %s %zd\n", argc, argv[1], i);
        rc = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got hit with segfault because the number of required arguments specified was done poorly. The main problem is here:

```
if (argc == 2)
```

The number of *actual* arguments passed by the user is equal to the number of required arguments *minus 1*<sup>**1**</sup>. It should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    // Number of arguments are either greater or lesser than 3
    // Handle the error
  }

  // Ok...
}
```

You can safely use the arguments now.

---

<sup>1. The calling command for the program, for example `./a.out` is also counted as an argument (`argv[0]`).</sup>